# Can constructor with private values produce LNK-Error?

Tags: c++, constructor

I've started to "port" my Java implementation of dynamic array to C++ and somehow i'm facing a strange linker error (LNK2019 and LNK2011) in my code, although i don't see any place which can produce such error.
I think it has something to do with constructor, but i can't find what exactly.
Thank you for your help!

DynStackArrayQueue.cpp (test class) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "DynArray.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    DynArray dynA (3, 6);
}
```

DynArray.h

```
#pragma once

class DynArray {
private:
    int growthFactor, maxOverhead;
    int elements[];
public:
    DynArray(int growthFactor, int maxOverhead);
}
```

DynArray.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "DynArray.h"

using namespace std;

DynArray::DynArray(int growthFactor, int maxOverhead) {
       this->growthFactor = growthFactor;
       this->maxOverhead = maxOverhead;
    }
```

The error itself:

[image: LNK-Error]

Comment: `int elements[];` is not a valid declaration in C++. There is a list of good books [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list); beyond punctuation and the spelling of some keywords, C++ doesn't have much in common with Java.

Comment: @molbdnilo 
1. Why? Should i enter some values there first?
2. No, the problem isn't in ```int elements[]```.

Comment: Did you add `DynArray.cpp` to your build?

Comment: The size of an array is fixed and must be specified at compile-time.

Comment: @molbdnilo oh, thanks! Didn't know that

Comment: @MaxAzatian, it may not be the cause of the problem you speak of, but it is definitely *a* problem.

Comment: @fas yep, added right at the start

Comment: @anastaciu ok, gonna fix it later (if i fix this LNK error). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a semicolon at the end of the class declaration. This leads to a compilation error, which you actually should be able to see before the linker error. Solution: add a semicolon after the closing brace of your `DynArray` class definition.